# line chart has white space when using adjust Width react native Gifted Chart

Tags: javascript, react-native, charts, react-native-chart-kit

I need to adjust and fix my chart width as per the data in the container, but when there is max data then it shows okay while there is min data then it will show some data and some white spaces, my requirement is just to remove white spaces and to show fix chart on the container. Also same as Bar Chart.
kindly help me, I will be really glad.
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the owner and maintainer of react-native-gifted-charts.
This issue is now fixed in version 1.3.1

We have introduced a new prop named `endSpacing` whose default value is 20. Set `endSpacing` to 0 if you want to remove the space at the right side of the chart.

Also when we set the prop `adjustToWidth` to true, `endSpacing` automatically sets to 0.

[Link to the GitHub issue](https://github.com/Abhinandan-Kushwaha/react-native-gifted-charts/issues/276)